# Creating a shortcut with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, shortcut-file

I'm trying to create a shortcut using PowerShell that opens certificates.

```
$shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).Createshortcut("desktop\Certificates.lnk")
$shortcut.TargetPath = ("C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe cryptui.dll,CryptUIStartCertMgr")
$shortcut.IconLocation = ("%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.DLL, 44")
$shortcut.Save()
```

What I currently have creates a shortcut with the target of...

```
"C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe cryptui.dll,CryptUIStartCertMgr"
```

When there the shortcut's target includes the "" it doesn't work. I've tried to remove them from the script, but then it launches the certificates gui once and creates a shortcut on the desktop targeted to this PC instead of certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The target executable and its arguments must be specified *separately*, namely in the `.TargetPath` and `.Arguments` property, respectively**.<sup>[1]</sup>

(Whatever you assign to `.TargetPath` is considered *just* an executable file path, and if it contains spaces, it is automatically and invariably enclosed in `"..."` for you.)

Therefore:

```
$shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).CreateShortcut('desktop\Certificates.lnk')
$shortcut.TargetPath = 'C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe' # Executable only
$shortcut.Arguments = 'cryptui.dll,CryptUIStartCertMgr'   # Args to pass to executable.
$shortcut.IconLocation = '%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.DLL, 44'
$shortcut.Save()
```

Note that I've removed unnecessary `(...)` enclosures and, for conceptual clarity, have switched from [expandable (double-quoted) strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) to [verbatim (single-quoted) strings (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), given that no string expansion (interpolation) is required in your code.

That said, for full robustness you could replace `'C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe'` with `"$env:SystemRoot\System32\rundll32.exe"` - for *instant* expansion - or `'%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe'` for letting `.CreateShortcut()` perform the expansion.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] This contrasts with creating a shortcut file *interactively*: In the Properties dialog presented by the Windows shell (File Explorer), the single `Target` field is a *concatenation* of these two underlying properties; that is, in the GUI you specify only *one* value - the entire command line - which is then split into executable name/path and arguments behind the scenes.</sup>

<sup>[2] It seems that the resulting shortcut file (`.lnk`) stores *both* the expanded and the unexpanded value. When *inspecting* a shortcut file's properties in File Explorer - and surprisingly also via getting the property values of a [`WshShortcut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k.aspx) object created with `(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).CreateShortcut()` - you only ever see the *expanded* values.</sup>